# Bike weight different from spec sheet

Tags: road-bike, weight

I just bought a brand new Canyon Endurace SL from the Canyon factory and started ridding it for about 10 days. On the spec sheet is only 7.6 Kg so I was pretty confident when a friend lifted it to check the weight. My ego and pride scatter to pieces when he said it was rather on the heavy side. And he was right, it does feel way heavier than I can recall.

Back home I get the balance out and check it for myself, and it displays something like 8.7Kg.

So where does all this extra weight comes from? My pedals are less than 500g a pair according to Shimano, a 40g bottle cage, two 35g lights for safety and a speed counter on the from rim (no more than 40g I assume). That doesn't sum to more than a Kilo. Can water get caught in the frame and/or rims after a wet day or a thorough wash? Did Canyon deliberately lie on the specs? Can my bike sneak out and feed itself over grease and power gels overnight?

I guess it's just my brain playing tricks on me...

Comment: Did you actually weight the bike yourself to get to 7.6 kg? Manufacturer-measured weights are notoriously smaller than actual weight. Not that they lie, but most often it's without pedals, smallish frame, lightest tires, ... I think it's really a perception issue.

Comment: What size is yours? What size do they specify the weight for? (if they don't it will be a small one).  What do you weigh it as if you strip it down to the conditions they specify? How are you weighing it? Luggage scales would be the best common device, or stand on bathroom svcales holding it, then subtract your own weight measured immediately before/after.

Comment: Is there food missing from your fridge? Most people think we lock our bikes to stop them being stolen but really it's to stop them snacking while we're not watching.

Comment: @ChrisH Or just put the front and rear wheels on a bathroom scale one after the other and add the two values.

Comment: @ChrisH, the specs are for a frame size M, mine is S, so it should even be a few grams less. Adding the pedals weight, it should be slightly over 8Kg. I should of weight the bike right after assembling it because now I am just left with assumptions that Canyon is being fully transparent on the spec sheet.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'll check the fridge, but to be scientifically valid, I'll have to get rid of my wife (and daughter) to eliminate any potential interference.

Comment: I used the "bathroom scale" technique, which is from a Dutch brand, therefore trusty (or is it?). I'll try the "wheel by wheel" weighing technique, I'm very curious of the result :)

Comment: Bathroom scales tend to be a bit variable, specially if they're pointer-based not digital.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've found bathroom scales to be a bit rubbish at the bottom end (stiction probably) so for a few kg I suggest doing it differently. There's also the need to keep it upright (pure sideways force)

Comment: i agree that bathroom scales are not that reliable, however I had a very similar experience with my bike (from another German direct sale manufacturer). Whilst there can be a small amount of variation in frame weights, it shouldn't be more than 100g or so.

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but did you check the weight for (and did you receive) the correct model?  The Endurance CF SL 7.0 is listed at 8.2kg, which adding pedals and accessories will come to your 8.7kg figure

Comment: @AndyP, I actually went for the **Endurace CF SL 8.0 SL** (that's right, it's twice SL!), which is listed as 7.6Kg only. 1€ a gram, that's exactly what costs weight saving in some bike families at Canyon

Comment: As I was saying, my scale seems ok and gives me consistent figures in normal cases. But it's true that without reliable hardware we could keep this delightful speculation going on for years. Next time I do maintenance over the bike, I'll remove the pedals and have another measurement. I'll try to set my hand on a luggage scale if I can.

Comment: @cmaster some bathroom scales are much worse than others for being very sensitive to weight distribution.  I've seen some where I can get the +/- 1kg, but repeatably by stepping off and on with my weight forwards/backwards, or just leaning.  The digital strain guage ones seem better in that regard, but more sensitive to uneven floors.

Comment: btw that's a light bike and you can ignore your friend.  Heavy is what I ride (my *fast* bike is nearly 15kg of steel, but for audaxes rather than racing).

Comment: @ChrisH you are right, someone that willingly hurts a man on such a sensitive matter of bike weight only deserves ignorance. For the scale, it's a digital one. I guess my daughter comes handy again, I'll test weighing us in different holding positions (arm stretched, shoulder or arm holding) and see how it affects the figures. And indeed, even and flat floor is a must for correct measurement.

Comment: If you know any Veterinarians, they often have a large flatbed scale suitable for weighing large dogs.  If weight is a concern, consider buying your own digital fishhook scales as seen on GCN etc.   Using the same tool every time will add to consistency.

Comment: My wife and I have kayaks of the same model, spec'd at 52 lbs.  Hers is 50.5 lbs and mine is 56 lbs.  That is $10\%$ of manufacturing variation.  Kayaks are hand laid up, so I would expect more variation than bikes.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with a Rose X-Lite 4 2018. My bike is 0.5kg heavier than the 6.7kg listed on their website which is for the frame one size *larger* and 150g *heavier* wheels. They state ±5% weight variation due to manufacturing tolerances which would only explain 335g difference. Maybe they simply take the sum of all parts and “forget” to add things like cables, screws, bar tape etc. Kind of fishy and dishonest. The bike is still awesome, so I’ve contented myself with the weight.

Comment: Things you never ask others.....How much they earn, how much their plane ticket cost and how much their bike really weighs.

Answer (score 4):

There is some variance in the manufacturers' claimed weight. Due to slight differences in the manufacturing process of the individual components, it is possible that the claimed weight was legitimate. If they weighed the smallest frame available and mated it to the lightest set of the specified wheels, the lightest saddle, etc, they could produce a bike that is lighter than anything that would come down the normal assembly line. Many brands specify that they don't list weights because of these variations. Some brands actually advertise the weight but don't specify the details such as frame size, was the frame painted, was bar tape installed etc.

Answer (score 0):

When they measured the frame it might be a size "S" or even "XS" for display. If you do have a bigger frame, your disc rotor is likely to have an increase in size as well. Dirt and dust may also be a contributing factor.

Comment: As stated in the comments, Canyon usually gives the weight for a size **M** bike, and mine is **S**. Now, if you have some figures or stats about how much dust and dirt adds to a bike, I would be interested!

Comment: Larger frames use larger disc rotors? Are you sure about that?